# wkhtmltopdf output to html response producing 0 byte file

Tags: c#, asp.net, wkhtmltopdf

I'm using wkhtmltopdf.exe on my server to convert some .aspx page based reports into pdf's that are then downloaded to the clients computer.  After extensive research I found this [blog post](http://tacticalnuclearstrike.com/2011/03/rendering-html-as-pdf-using-wkhtmltopdf-in-asp-net/) with an example that seemed to get at what I want to accomplish. I attempted to adapt it to my own uses however I can't get it to work.  The response from the page is a .pdf file but it is 0 bytes in length.  I been researching solutions for converting an rendered aspx page to .pdf for close to a day and a half now with no luck - this solution is the closest I've come and I think I'm just missing something simple and it will work.

Please see code below - I would appreciate any guidance you can provide to make this work!

```
public partial class PDFOut : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string args = string.Format("\"{0}\" - ", Request.Form["url"]);//'http://www.google.com' is what I'm passing for testing
        var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(Server.MapPath("\\tools\\wkhtmltopdf.exe"), args)
        {
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true
        };
        var proc = new Process { StartInfo = startInfo };
        proc.Start();

        string output = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        byte[] buffer = proc.StandardOutput.CurrentEncoding.GetBytes(output);
        proc.WaitForExit();
        proc.Close();
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=test.pdf");
        Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

Comment: I read the `wkhtmltopdf` in the title from the main feed and I was sure it's spam. `wkhtmltopdf`? we're really running out of names...  :P

Comment: I've always had it write the PDF to a temp directory. I was unaware that it would write the pdf to standard out. Have you tried running your command from an actual command line?

Comment: I don't believe wkhtmltopdf has any examples of outputting the resulting file to standard out. http://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt I could be wrong though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like this work for you? Write the PDF to a temp directory, then read the PDF and finally delete the temp file?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string outputFile = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Path.GetRandomFileName(), ".pdf");
        string args = string.Format("\"{0}\" \"{1}\"", Request.Form["url"], outputFile );
        var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(Server.MapPath("\\tools\\wkhtmltopdf.exe"), args)
        {
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true
        };
        var proc = new Process { StartInfo = startInfo };
        proc.Start();

        proc.WaitForExit();
        proc.Close();

        var buffer= File.ReadAllBytes(outputFile);
        File.Delete(outputFile);

        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=test.pdf");
        Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
        Response.End();
    }
```

Comment: I had to make some adjustments to where you put the temp file but otherwise It worked like a charm!  Thank you!!